# Network error. Connection resets in any application

Tags: networking, ssl, connection

Good evening everyone!
I have a problem which chases me for a while now and it really disturbs me.
The problem is that whenever I try to download anything larger than a few megabytes my connection interrupts and immediately restores back. This happens in any application whether it is a browser or git or IDE or installer which downloads sources from the Internet. When it happens in browser I can't just click "Retry" button and it continues downloading from the moment it stopped but it really pisses me off because I have to click retry for like 20 times to download 100mb file. When it happens in any java enviroment the exception looks like javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!.
Things I've tried to solve this issue:

1. Disable antivirus
2. Disable VPN
3. Reset hosts
4. Reset TCP/IP
5. Reset WinSock
6. Reset browser cache
7. Reset router to factory settings
8. Update WiFi addapter drivers
9. Change WiFi channel
10. Disable firewall
11. Run AdwCleaner
12. Run Antivirus check
    And many other things. I will append the list if I remember anythig else.
    At first I thought it was because of WiFi router, but other PCs in this network don't suffer from this issue. WiFi addapter also seems to be OK, other PCs work fine with it.
    I even tried to catch the moment of reset in WireShark and it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/acTKe.png

This question is my only hope to solve this issue, please help.

My PC configuration is:

OS: Windows 10

CPU: Intel Core i5-7600K

WiFi adapter: TP-Link Archer T2U V1

Network Card: Intel® 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Full list of installed applications:

7-Zip 19.00 (x64)   Igor Pavlov 07.08.2020  4,96 МБ 19.00   Все пользователи

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC - Russian   Adobe Systems Incorporated  26.09.2020  329 МБ  20.012.20048    Все пользователи

Altova XMLSpy® 2013 Enterprise Edition  Altova  20.06.2019  502 МБ  2013.00.00  Все пользователи

Android Studio  Google LLC  06.10.2020      4.0 Все пользователи

AnyDesk philandro Software GmbH 08.08.2020  2,00 МБ ad 6.0.7    Все пользователи

Attribute Changer 9.50  Romain Petges   21.01.2020  5,91 МБ 9.50    Все пользователи

Bandicam    Bandicam.com    22.09.2020  88,1 МБ 4.6.3.1725  Все пользователи

Bandicam MPEG-1 Decoder Bandicam.com    22.09.2020          Все пользователи

Bitrix24 for Windows    Bitrix  07.08.2020  85,9 МБ 8.2.69.48   Все пользователи

Blender Blender Foundation  05.10.2020  506 МБ  2.90.1  rsv

Cisco AnyConnect AMP Enabler Module Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  248 КБ  4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Diagnostics and Reporting Tool Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  4,48 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect ISE Posture Module Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  3,50 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Network Access Manager Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  5,14 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Network Visibility Module  Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  2,32 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Posture Module Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  17,3 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020      4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Start Before Login Module  Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  1,17 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Umbrella Roaming Security Module   Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  4,23 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Cisco AnyConnect Web Security Module    Cisco Systems, Inc. 25.05.2020  2,96 МБ 4.7.03052   Все пользователи

Classic Shell   IvoSoft 19.11.2019  13,1 МБ 4.3.1   Все пользователи

Cortana Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      2.2007.24732.0  rsv

Counter-Strike  Valve   07.08.2020          Все пользователи

Counter-Strike: Source  Valve   07.08.2020          Все пользователи

DBeaver 7.1.3 (current user)    DBeaver Corp    07.08.2020      7.1.3   rsv

Discord Discord Inc.    10.09.2020  58,7 МБ 0.0.308 rsv

Docker Desktop  Docker Inc. 07.08.2020      2.3.0.3 Все пользователи

Dolby Access    Dolby Laboratories  03.09.2020      3.4.255.0   rsv

EmEditor (64-bit)   Emurasoft, Inc. 10.01.2020  130 МБ  19.5.0  rsv

English (United States) Local Experience Pack   Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020      19041.3.3.0 rsv

FileZilla Client 3.48.1 Tim Kosse   07.08.2020  27,6 МБ 3.48.1  Все пользователи

FileZilla Server    FileZilla Project   07.08.2020  6,04 МБ beta 0.9.60 Все пользователи

Garry's Mod Facepunch Studios   07.08.2020          Все пользователи

Git Extensions 3.4.3.9999   Git Extensions Team 03.09.2020  56,8 МБ 3.4.3.9999  Все пользователи

Git version 2.21.0  The Git Development Community   03.06.2019  246 МБ  2.21.0  Все пользователи

glogg       07.08.2020      v1.1.4-x86_64   Все пользователи

Google Chrome   Google LLC  24.09.2020      85.0.4183.121   Все пользователи

Gram Wallet version 0.9.8   Telegram FZ-LLC 08.05.2020  28,4 МБ 0.9.8   rsv

HashTab 6.0.0.34    Implbits Software   07.08.2020      6.0.0.34    Все пользователи

HashTools 4.3   Binary Fortress Software    29.04.2020  8,97 МБ 4.3.0.0 Все пользователи

Hotline Miami 2: Wrong Number   Dennaton Games  07.08.2020          Все пользователи

IBM MQ (Installation1)  IBM 30.08.2019  763 МБ  9.1.3.0 Все пользователи

IBM MQ Explorer V9.1    IBM 07.08.2020  631 МБ  9.1.3.0 Все пользователи

IDA Freeware 7.0    Hex-Rays SA 24.10.2019  62,9 МБ 7.0 Все пользователи

Insomnia    Kong    17.07.2020  88,2 МБ 2020.3.3    rsv

Intel(R) Processor Graphics Intel Corporation   01.08.2020      27.20.100.7989  Все пользователи

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3  JetBrains s.r.o.    07.08.2020      191.7479.19 Все пользователи

iTunes  Apple Inc.  01.08.2020      12108.5.48031.0 rsv

Java 7 Update 80 (64-bit)   Oracle  03.12.2019  118 МБ  7.0.800 Все пользователи

Java 8 Update 221 (64-bit)  Oracle Corporation  05.08.2019  43,8 МБ 8.0.2210.11 Все пользователи

Java 9.0.4 (64-bit) Oracle Corporation  23.10.2019  205 МБ  9.0.4.0 Все пользователи

Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 80 (64-bit)    Oracle  03.12.2019  245 МБ  1.7.0.800   Все пользователи

Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 211 (64-bit)   Oracle Corporation  03.06.2019  368 МБ  8.0.2110.12 Все пользователи

Java(TM) 6 Update 45 (64-bit)   Oracle  17.09.2019  92,3 МБ 6.0.450 Все пользователи

Java(TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 45 (64-bit)    Oracle  17.09.2019  128 МБ  1.6.0.450   Все пользователи

Java(TM) SE Development Kit 9.0.4 (64-bit)  Oracle Corporation  23.10.2019  590 МБ  9.0.4.0 Все пользователи

JetBrains PyCharm 2019.1.3  JetBrains s.r.o.    07.08.2020      191.7479.30 Все пользователи

Kaspersky Endpoint Security для Windows АО "Лаборатория Касперского"    14.04.2020  271 МБ  11.3.0.773  Все пользователи

KYOCERA Print Center    KYOCERA Document Solutions Inc  16.07.2020      2.4.21902.0 rsv

Meld    The Meld project    06.06.2019  103 МБ  3.20.0  Все пользователи

Microsoft Edge  Корпорация Майкрософт   02.10.2020      85.0.564.68 Все пользователи

Microsoft Edge      02.10.2020          rsv

Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - ru-ru    Microsoft Corporation   20.09.2020      16.0.12527.21104    Все пользователи

Microsoft OneDrive  Microsoft Corporation   02.09.2020  146 МБ  20.143.0716.0003    rsv

Microsoft Pay   Microsoft Corporation   10.09.2019      2.4.18324.0 rsv

Microsoft Solitaire Collection  Microsoft Studios   31.08.2020      4.7.8101.0  rsv

Microsoft Store Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      12008.1001.1.0  rsv

Microsoft System CLR Types для SQL Server 2019 CTP2.2   Microsoft Corporation   20.01.2020  4,34 МБ 15.0.1200.24    Все пользователи

Microsoft Teams Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020  94,8 МБ 1.3.00.21759    rsv

Microsoft To Do Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      2.25.32322.0    rsv

Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.30501    Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020  20,5 МБ 12.0.30501.0    Все пользователи

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.25.28508  Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020  22,5 МБ 14.25.28508.3   Все пользователи

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.24.28127  Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020  20,1 МБ 14.24.28127.4   Все пользователи

Microsoft Visual Studio Code (User) Microsoft Corporation   09.09.2020  242 МБ  1.48.2  rsv

Microsoft Visual Studio Installer   Microsoft Corporation   10.01.2020      2.4.1080.1113   Все пользователи

Microsoft Whiteboard    Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      20.10810.5396.0 rsv

Mozilla Firefox 78.0.2 (x64 ru) Mozilla 07.08.2020  201 МБ  78.0.2  Все пользователи

Mozilla Maintenance Service Mozilla 07.08.2020  323 КБ  67.0    Все пользователи

mRemoteNG   Next Generation Software    15.04.2020  87,0 МБ 1.76.20.24615   Все пользователи

Network Speed Test  Microsoft Research  28.06.2019      1.0.0.23    rsv

Node.js Node.js Foundation  29.08.2019  53,2 МБ 10.16.3 Все пользователи

Notepad++ (64-bit x64)  Notepad++ Team  07.08.2020  21,0 МБ 7.8.6   Все пользователи

Npcap   Nmap Project    07.08.2020      0.9991  Все пользователи

Null-modem emulator (com0com)   Vyacheslav Frolov   07.08.2020  434 КБ  3.0.0.0 Все пользователи

OCS Inventory NG Agent 2.3.1.0  OCS Inventory NG Team   07.08.2020      2.3.1.0 Все пользователи

Office  Microsoft Corporation   22.07.2020      18.2006.1031.0  rsv

Office Lens Microsoft Corporation   24.03.2020      16.0.32000.0    rsv

OneNote for Windows 10  Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      16001.13127.20190.0 rsv

Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.0.14 Oracle Corporation  02.12.2019  227 МБ  6.0.14  Все пользователи

Paint 3D    Microsoft Corporation   18.06.2020      6.2004.20027.0  rsv

PostgreSQL 11   PostgreSQL Global Development Group 14.04.2020      11  Все пользователи

PostgreSQL 11 (64bit)   Postgres Professional Russia    07.08.2020  907 МБ  11.7    Все пользователи

Print 3D    Microsoft Corporation   28.06.2019      3.3.791.0   rsv

PrintDialog     13.08.2020          rsv

Pritunl Client  Pritunl 23.03.2020  190 МБ  1.0.2317.40 Все пользователи

Progress Telerik Fiddler    Progress Software Corporation   21.09.2020  15,7 МБ 5.0.20202.18177 rsv

PuTTY release 0.71 (64-bit) Simon Tatham    13.07.2019  3,79 МБ 0.71.0.0    Все пользователи

Python Launcher Python Software Foundation  11.06.2019  1,76 МБ 3.7.6657.0  Все пользователи

qBittorrent 4.2.5   The qBittorrent project 06.10.2020  126 МБ  4.2.5   Все пользователи

Realtek High Definition Audio Driver    Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 07.08.2020      6.0.1.7910  Все пользователи

Remote Desktop Connection Manager   Microsoft Corporation   17.09.2019  1,22 МБ 2.7.14060   Все пользователи

Robo 3T 1.3.1   3T Software Labs Ltd    07.08.2020      1.3.1   Все пользователи

Skype   Skype   07.08.2020      15.63.76.0  rsv

SoapUI 5.5.0    SmartBear Software  07.08.2020      5.5.0   Все пользователи

Steam   Valve Corporation   07.08.2020      2.10.91.91  Все пользователи

Super Hexagon   Terry Cavanagh  07.08.2020          Все пользователи

Sway    Microsoft Corporation   15.04.2020      18.2003.51105.0 rsv

Teams Machine-Wide Installer    Microsoft Corporation   25.01.2020  92,6 МБ 1.2.0.34161 Все пользователи

TeamViewer  TeamViewer  26.09.2020      15.10.5 Все пользователи

TightVNC    GlavSoft LLC.   28.06.2019  2,98 МБ 2.8.11.0    Все пользователи

Total Commander 64-bit (Remove or Repair)   Ghisler Software GmbH   07.08.2020      9.22a   Все пользователи

TP-Link Archer T2U Driver   TP-Link 06.10.2020      1.0.0   Все пользователи

TreeSize Free V4.4.2    JAM Software    10.08.2020  10,5 МБ 4.4.2   Все пользователи

UltraISO v9.7.1.3519    EZB Systems, Inc.   06.10.2020  7,36 МБ 9.7.1   Все пользователи

Unlocker    ajua Custom Installers  23.11.2019  144 КБ  1.9.2   Все пользователи

Visual Studio Community 2019    Microsoft Corporation   20.01.2020      16.4.29709.97   Все пользователи

Windows SDK AddOn   Microsoft Corporation   20.01.2020  152 КБ  10.1.0.0    Все пользователи

Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.18362.1 Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020  544 МБ  10.1.18362.1    Все пользователи

WinSCP 5.17.2   Martin Prikryl  22.03.2020  96,0 МБ 5.17.2  Все пользователи

Wireshark 3.2.4 64-bit  The Wireshark developer community, https://www.wireshark.org    07.08.2020  178 МБ  3.2.4   Все пользователи

Xbox Game bar   Microsoft Corporation   08.06.2020      1.54.4001.0 rsv

Xbox Game Bar   Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      5.420.8043.0    rsv

Xbox Game Speech Window Microsoft Corporation   28.06.2019      1.21.13002.0    rsv

Xbox Identity Provider  Microsoft Corporation   03.08.2020      12.67.21001.0   rsv

Xbox Live   Microsoft Corporation   28.06.2019      1.24.10001.0    rsv

Zoom    Zoom Video Communications, Inc. 09.09.2020  9,76 МБ 5.2.3 (45120.0906)  rsv

Агент администрирования Kaspersky Security Center   "Лаборатория Касперского"   07.08.2020  125 МБ  12.0.0.7734 Все пользователи

Будильники и часы   Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020      10.2007.3.0 rsv

Ваш телефон Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      1.20081.116.0   rsv

ЕАИС Стандарт-ЭЦП 2.3.0 CITTU   01.09.2020  9,67 МБ 2.3.0   Все пользователи

Записки (Майкрософт)    Microsoft Corporation   07.08.2020      3.7.142.0   rsv

Запись голоса   Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020      10.2007.2.0 rsv

Калькулятор Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020      10.2007.1.0 rsv

Камера  Microsoft Corporation   25.06.2020      2020.504.40.0   rsv

Карты   Microsoft Corporation   11.08.2020      10.2006.11.0    rsv

Кино и ТВ   Microsoft Corporation   20.06.2020      10.20032.16211.0    rsv

Компаньон консоли Xbox  Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020      48.68.29001.0   rsv

КриптоПро CSP   Компания КриптоПро  05.07.2019      4.0.9944    Все пользователи

Люди    Microsoft Corporation   07.04.2020      10.1909.10841.0 rsv

Музыка Groove   Microsoft Corporation   15.05.2020      10.20032.12611.0    rsv

Набросок на фрагменте экрана    Microsoft Corporation   26.09.2019      10.1907.2471.0  rsv

Надстройка модуля мультимедиа для приложения "Фотографии"   Microsoft Corporation   04.06.2020      1.0.0.0 rsv

Пакет локализованного интерфейса на русском Microsoft Corporation   14.08.2020      19041.8.19.0    rsv

Погода  Microsoft Corporation   24.03.2020      4.36.20714.0    rsv

Портал смешанной реальности Microsoft Corporation   06.08.2020      2000.20071.1133.0   rsv

Почта и Календарь   Microsoft Corporation   30.07.2020      16005.13110.41006.0 rsv

Расширения для VP9-видео    Microsoft Corporation   10.06.2020      1.0.31471.0 rsv

Расширения для изображений HEIF Microsoft Corporation   02.07.2020      1.0.31572.0 rsv

Расширения для изображений Webp Microsoft Corporation   01.06.2020      1.0.31251.0 rsv

Расширения для интернет-мультимедиа Microsoft Corporation   12.09.2019      1.0.20875.0 rsv

Советы  Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      9.9.32102.0 rsv

Средство 3D-просмотра   Microsoft Corporation   18.05.2020      7.2004.20022.0  rsv

Техническая поддержка   Microsoft Corporation   08.06.2020      10.2004.31291.0 rsv

Удаленный рабочий стол  Microsoft Corporation   03.09.2020      10.2.1524.0 rsv

Узел для покупок в Store    Microsoft Corporation   31.08.2020      12008.1001.1.0  rsv

Установщик приложения   Microsoft Corporation   05.11.2019      1.0.32912.0 rsv

Фотографии  Microsoft Corporation   15.07.2020      2020.20070.10002.0  rsv

Центр отзывов   Microsoft Corporation   13.12.2019      1.1907.3152.0   rsv

Центр управления графикой Intel®    INTEL CORP  31.08.2020      1.100.2765.0    rsv

Яндекс.Музыка   Yandex  14.08.2020      4.21.7529.0 rsv

Comment: What are you connecting to?  Is that connection (external to your computer) limiting your bandwidth?   School, Business, Institution.

Comment: I'm connecting to any kind of resource on the Internet. And if you mean what my connection goes through then it goes through wireless router Sagemcom F@st 1744 v4. I have admin access to that and it doesn't limit my bandwidth

Comment: +1 for being the first person I have seen post relevant details

Comment: Considering everything at the app level of the osi model is having problems, this makes me think either your tcp/IP stack is corrupt, or something is interfering with it. This also happens when wired to the router?

Comment: I don't have an ability to check it. But anyway I find a way to prevent this from happening. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the cause of this weird behaviour but the solution that worked for me was to disable IPv6 and leave only IPv4. Don't know why that worked, maybe because of old WiFi router or buggy drivers for WiFi adapter. But anyway I hope this will help someone some day